# What is the best way to create a single observable stream, subscribe to it in template, and perform all CRUD operations on the same stream?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a component called merchandise. I would like to be able to:
1. Have a single observable stream to which I can subscribe to in my component template using the async pipe
2. Perform Create, Retrieve, Update and Delete operations on items inside the stream array, and emit the updated array in that stream.

This would replace my current implementation of having to subscribe to and unsubscribe from service methods that currently perform this action for me and in the 'recipe' or the pipe-able operators in the component. I now update the array in the component and bind to that array in the template.

For example in my component I have the following:

```
onSubmit(){
this.merchandiseService.createGearItemAction(this.gearItem);
}
```

in my service I have the following:

```
private newGearItemAction: Subject<GearItem> = new Subject<GearItem>();

  createGearItemAction(gearItem: GearItem | null): void {
    this.newGearItemAction.next(gearItem);
  }
```

Then I would like to be able to do something like this but for any CRUD operations not just create
(in the service.ts file)

```
gearItemsLatest$ = combineLatest([
    this.newGearItemAction,
    this.merchandiseGearItems$
  ]).pipe(
    map(([newGearItem, gearItems]: [GearItem, GearItem[]]) => {
      console.log("trying to post");
      this.http.post<GearItem>(
        this.merchandiseGearItemsUrl,
        JSON.stringify(newGearItem)
      );
      gearItems = [...gearItems, newGearItem];
      return gearItems;
    })
  );
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You might be interested in a library I wrote to wrap a lot of this kind of functionality up call ngx-rxcache https://github.com/adriandavidbrand/ngx-rxcache read about it here https://medium.com/@adrianbrand/angular-state-management-with-rxcache-468a865fc3fb

Answer (score 0):

Doing a combine latest isn't going to persist the new item once another is added, I would use a single behavior subject and push the result into that.

```
gearItems$ = new BehaviorSubject<GearItem[]>([]);

add(gearItem: GearItem) {
  this.gearItems$.next([...this.gearItems$.getValue(), gearItem]);
}
```

and in your component you just add the observable

```
gearItems$ = this.merchandiseService.gearItems$;
```

and in the view display the gearItems$ with the async pipe

```
<ng-container *ngIf="gearItems$ | async as gearItems">
  <div *ngFor="let gearItem of gearItems">{{gearItem | json}}</div>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: so I need to make an async call to the backend to persist the new gearItem, same goes for update and delete. Would it make sense to make that async call in the add method in the service, like this.http.post<GearItem>(...).pipe(tap(res => this.gearItems$([...this.gearItems$, v]))); Or is this an anti-pattern?

Comment: I would push the item into the array on success of the post to the api. Read the article I wrote that I posted above, covers a lot of what you want to do. https://medium.com/@adrianbrand/angular-state-management-with-rxcache-468a865fc3fb